# SSH only after login?

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, systemd, openssh

I've freshly setup a rather standard current Arch Linux and encounter a problem that I can not get a grip on:

1. DHCP service is enabled and network is online (ping succeeds with hostname and IP address)
2. OpenSSH service is enabled
3. OpenSSH config allows public key and password

But I can not connect via SSH **unless I also log in** locally. Once I logged in locally once, I can logout in and out via SSH without problems, even when the local session is exited.

Journal says that SSH server starts up well before the local login.

Edit: Error message from Putty is "Connection refused"

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "can not connect".  Does it refuse the TCP connection? Does it accept the connection but deny your key and/or password?  Adding to your question the output of `ssh -vvv user@host` and the contents of the SSH daemon's log when attempting a connection would be helpful.

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted?  If it is, the system can't see your home dir until you login, thereby un-encrypting the home dir.

Comment: @MERM are you aware of any workaround for this problem?

Comment: @MERM thanks for mentioning this possibility, it applied to my case and was solved with instructions at:  
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install and enable haveged to generate sufficient entropy for the cryptographic exchange of keys. Possibly related to [this bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/58355).

Comment: You may want to add how to check the entropy on the system... `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` and list an OK value (>1000) for comparison...

Comment: installing havegd and enabling the service solved the issue!

Comment: @Arne you should check if it is still needed with 4.19 when you update to that series.